# What are the rules for adding members to Python methods safely?

Tags: python, function, dynamic, attributes

I'm looking at code like this:

```
def foo():
    return 42

foo.x = 5
```

This obviously adds a member to the function object named `foo`.  I find this very useful as it makes these function objects look very similar to Objects with a `__call__` function.

Are there rules I must follow to make sure I don't cause problems in future updates to Python, such as names that I must avoid?  Perhaps there is a PEP or documentation section that mentions rules?

Comment: In Python, this is called monkey patching.  Searching for that term will bring up a ton of information.

Comment: @FrankYellin no, this is not an example of monkey-patching. No functionality is being replaced.

Comment: @MartijnPieters.  I've seen the term refer both to modifications of existing code and to adding new attributes.  I'll note that the next answerer also refers to it as monkey patching.

Comment: @FrankYellin: I was at the company where the term was invented, back in 1999. We specifically referred to replacing or augmenting existing functionality. That may involve setting attributes somewhere, but that's like calling hammering in a nail as 'making a chair'. What the OP is doing is just setting an attribute on an object that supports attributes.

Answer (score 7):

There are no rules, other than to take the [reserved classes of identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers) into account. Specifically, try to avoid using `dunder` names:

> System-defined names, informally known as “dunder” names. *[...]* *Any* use of `__*__` names, in any context, that does not follow explicitly documented use, is subject to breakage without warning.

There is otherwise *nothing special* about functions accepting arbitrary attributes; almost anything in Python accepts arbitrary attributes if there is a place to put them (which is, almost always, a `__dict__` attribute).

Within the Python standard library, function attributes are used to link decorator wrapper functions to the original wrapped function (via the [`functools.update_wrapper()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper) and it's side-kick, the [`@functools.wraps()` decorator function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps)), and to attach state and methods to a function when augmented by decorators (e.g. the [`singledispatch()` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) adds several methods and a registry to the decorated function).

Answer (score -2):

It is a good technique. Rule is not shadow any dunder names which have special meanings.

Here is a good way to implement a singleton:

```
import faker

def my_fake_data():
      if not getattr(my_fake_data, 'factory', None):
          my_fake_data.factory = faker.Faker()
      return my_fake_data.factory
```

Monkey patching uses a similar technique (setting a class attribute instead pf a function attribute) but for more "devious" reasons such as changing the implementation of a previously defined class.

Comment: Function attributes have almost **nothing** to do with [monkeypatching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch).  Why even bring that up? Of all the objects that take attributes, function objects are the *least likely* to be involved in the vast majority of monkey-patching operations.

Comment: Have updated answer to make it more accurate. @MartijnPieters